# Eliminate for loops in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I am having a scenario in which. I iterate over a list of DataFrames. Perform same type of operation on each using a FOR LOOP, and store the transformed data frame in a Map(String -> DataFrame).

```
for (df <- dfList)
{
    //perform some transformation of dataframe
    dfMap = dfMap + ("some_name", df)
}
```

This solution is working fine. But in a sequential manner. I want to make use of async to achieve parallelism and performance improvements. Such that the transformations on each df occur parallelly making using of distributed processing capabilities of Spark.

Comment: can you post full code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
def logic(df: DataFrame):Map[String,DataFrame] = {
    // Return Map[String,DataFrame] 
}

val dfa = // DataFrame 1
val dfb = // DataFrame 2
val dfc = // DataFrame 3

Seq(dfa,dfb,dfc,dfd)
.par // Parallel
.map(logic) // invoking logic function for every dataframe.
.reduce( _ ++ _ ) // Final result in Map["aaa" -> dfa,"bbb" -> dfb,"ccc" -> dfc]
```

**Update**

```
def writeToMap(a: Int, i: Int) = Map(a -> i)
def doOperation(a: Int)=writeToMap(a,a+10)
val list = Seq.range(0, 33) 
list.par.map(x => doOperation(x))
```

Comment: does par guarantees execution for each element in Seq??

Comment: I have used par in a simple list of 10K variables and print them. It skipped for some. That is why asking

Comment: i am not sure on that ... i have not faced this issue in my production code... if you don't want use this ```.par``` try some other libraries like monix.

Comment: ` val list = Seq.range(0, 10000)
    list.par.foreach(x => println(doOperation(x)+","))
    println(map.toString().split("\\,").length)`

This is giving me number less than 10K, everytime I ran.

Comment: what is map variable in above code.. ?? and what is this function will do - doOperation

Comment: object Test {

  var map = Map(1 -> 2)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val list = Seq.range(0, 33)
    list.par.foreach(x => println(doOperation(x)+","))
    println(map.toString().split("\\,").length)
  }

  def writeToMap(a: Int, i: Int) = {
    map = map + (a -> i)
  }

  def doOperation(a: Int): Int={
    println("In funct doOperation for "+a)
    writeToMap(a,a+10)
    return a+10
  }

}

Comment: you are doing wrong, in parallel threads never try to update variables in your case you are updating map this will always give you wrong result.. If i understood correctly you can get same result with this - list.par.map(i => writeToMap(i,i+10)).reduce(_ ++ _).size

Comment: changed your writeToMap function - def writeToMap(a: Int, i: Int) = { Map(a -> i) }

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Does par guarantees that every execution is done in parallel? I mean does it not skip some of the operations being asynchronous in nature.?

Answer (score 1):

```
val dfList : List[DataFrame] =  // Your Dataframe list 

val dfMap : Map[String,DataFrame] = dfList.map("some_name" -> _).toMap
```

`.map` do the mapping of each element with the Pair
`.toMap` would aggregate the result to a Map.

Note : `some_name` should be unique for every dataframe

Comment: Where will the transformation code be executed in the above code snippet?

Comment: on driver as mapping creating dataframes map is not a heavy operation

Comment: That is a heavy opreration: Converting a Fixed Width File(DF) to a DF